# Новое окно в браузере Chrome

Tags: extjs

Как открыть через `EXT.js` новое окно в хроме.
В контроллер пробывал через:

```
window.open('../guide/ru/CONTENTS.HTM');
```

но она открывает в второй вкладке, гугление не особо помогло!

p.s м.б. кто знает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так

```
 window.open("https://www.google.kz/", "google","width=1200,height=700,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
```